# Suppose that 4 fair dice are rolled. Let $M$ be the minimum of 4 numbers rolled. Find $E(M)$

Tags: probability

Suppose that 4 fair dice are rolled. Let $M$ be the minimum of 4 numbers rolled. What are the possible values of $M$. Find $E(M)$

I can't seem to get the correct answer.

The possible values of M are { $1,2,3,4,5,6$ }

$P(M=1)=\frac{1}{6}$

$P(M=2)=\frac{5^3}{6^4}$

$P(M=3)=\frac{4^3}{6^4}$

$P(M=4)=\frac{3^3}{6^4}$

$P(M=5)=\frac{2^3}{6^4}$

$P(M=6)=\frac{1}{6^4}$

Did i not calculate the probabilities correctly? I took it to be that say if $M=i$, $P(M=i)=\frac {1\cdot (6-i+1)^3}{6^4}$ by solely basing on the possible outcomes. I thought of permutating each case but that just gets me to a probability of more than 1 which is not possible. I am pretty sure my probability formula is wrong.

Comment: The probability that $M=1$, say, is not $\frac 16$.  To compute that one look at the complement, the probability that all rolls exceed $1$.  That probability is clearly $\frac {5^4}{6^4}$ so $P(M=1)=1-\frac {5^4}{6^4}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  Are you possibly thinking about the max?

Comment: Yes, got it backwards.

Comment: oh.. so i got it in reverse.. Damn.. that was a rookie mistake. Thanks.. i totally did not see that. Thanks for both of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Out of $6^4$ ways to roll four dice:

$1$ will give a minimum of $6$ (all four dice must show $6$).

$2^4-1$ will give a minimum of $5$ (all four must be greater than or equal to $5$, but not all $4$ may be greater than $5$).

$3^4-2^4$ will give a minimum of $4$.

Etc.

Comment: @zhoraster. You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A helpful formula: If $X$ is a non-negative integer r.v., then 
$$
E[X] = \sum_{k\ge 1} P(X\ge k).
$$
Hence 
$$
E[M] = \sum_{k= 1}^6 \frac{(6-k+1)^4}{6^4} = \frac{2275}{1296}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

- $P(M=k)=P(M\geq k)-P(M\geq k+1)$
- $P(M\geq k)=P(D_1\geq k\wedge\cdots\wedge D_4\geq k)=P(D_1\geq k)\times\cdots\times P(D_4\geq k)$
- Since $M$ is nonnegative we have: $\mathbb EM=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(M\geq k)$

Answer (score 0):

Added question:

Since the question is asking for the expectation of minimum number, why is it that $E(X)$ isn't given by $$P(X\ge1)*1 \ + \ P(X\ge2)*2 \ + \ ... $$ but simply the sum of all probabilities? Can someone explain to me the logic behind this? Thank you!